# How to make the height of iframe element same as button element?

Tags: html, css

I have an `<iframe>` and an `<a>` in a `<div>` with inline-block class, however it turned out they are different heights even when I set the same height for both of the elements. Did I miss something?

html:

```
<div class="inline-block w-100">

    <a><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=...=button_count&size=large&appId=XXXXXXX&width=88&height=28"
               width="88" height="28" style="border:none;overflow:hidden"
               scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true"
               allow="encrypted-media"></iframe></a>
    <a class="btn btn-success" href="..."
       style="height: 28"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"
                             style="max-height: 28">enquiries</i></a>

</div>
```

Comment: can you post your css?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change ***iframe*** height to **100%** which it will take its parent component's (**a** tag) height. And then giving height to the **a** tag will be enough to solve your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the the iframe at `width: 100%; height: 100%;` and set the size of its wrapper. I dont see your styling but you can also could have trouble with different `display` properties in your code

```css
.inline-block {
  border: 1px solid;
  display: flex;
}

a {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 88px;
  height: 28px;
  margin: 0 20px;
}

iframe {
  background: red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="inline-block w-100">

            <a><iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/share_button.php?href=...=button_count&size=large&appId=XXXXXXX" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe></a>
  
            <a class="btn btn-success" href="..." style="height: 28"><i class="fa fa-whatsapp my-float"style="max-height: 28">enquiries</i></a>


</div>
```